# MediaPlayer Url issue Only on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, url, media-player, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

After Calling the below method The app appears to be stuck on the loading screen and stop responding ,I'm performing my tests on a WiFi network so the connection should not 
   be the issue. Testing with Android M 6.0.0 works fine, this only occurs 
   for 6.0.1. Quite annoying, has anybody a hint

---

```
   fun getMusic() {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url)
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.start()
      }
```

---

```
My url :http://www.islamicaudio.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/2016-07-23-தெளிவு-6-தொழுகையில்-கழா-இருக்கிறதா-islam-in-tamil-mubarak-madani.mp3
```

---

```
this is the Error

   java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1080)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1041)
    at com.codenex.getbug.MainActivity.getMusic(MainActivity.kt:79)
    at com.codenex.getbug.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:55)
```